# Is parallel_do_feeder thread safe?

Tags: c++, tbb

The following code has concurrency issues. Here `inDegVec` is a global `int *`, and `getGUID()` and `getTime()` are innocuous accessors for POD variables.

```
void operator () ( GNode& src,
                      tbb::parallel_do_feeder<GNode>& feed_it )
        const 
{

            std::list<GNode> addNodes;             

            // some thread-safe code that populates addNodes

            while (!addNodes.empty()) {
                feed_it.add(addNodes.front());
                addNodes.pop_front();
            } 

            if (inDegVec[srcAVI->getUID()] == 0) {
                // srcAVI is still the minimum among its neighbors
                if (srcAVI->getTime() < colTime) {
                    //lwl.push (src);
                    //tbb::mutex::scoped_lock lock(histMutex);
                    assert(addNodes.empty());
                    feed_it.add(src);
                }  
           } 


};
```

If I wrap the `while`/`if` blocks in a mutex, the code works. But why is this necessary? Is `parallel_do_feeder::add()` not thread-safe? The example code I've seen (such as http://llpanorama.wordpress.com/2008/03/09/parallel_do-parallel-done/) use no synchronization, suggesting that it is... and I don't see a discussion of parallel_do_feeder's thread safety in the TBB manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `parallel_do_feeder` is thread safe.

Is the copy constructor of `GNode` thread safe? The instance of `GNode` passed to `parallel_do_feeder::add()` is **copied** into a task that will process it (possibly in another thread).